# Understanding this usage of も

Tags: grammar, particle-も

I have uncertainty interpreting も in the below sentence.

> なんなら自分自身**も**、ゲームのプレイヤーキャラ位に思っていて、どことなく他人事のように考えている。([source](https://youngjump.jp/oshinoko/novel_45510/novel_03.html))

I thought も marks 自分自身 as a subject but that will make 他人事のように考えている nonsense. So I think も is a substitute for を here? Then, ゲームのプレイヤーキャラ位に思っていて、どことなく他人事のように考えている will be understood as "think of herself as a player character in some game and treat herself as outside person (NPC)…? It sounds bit contradictory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it marks the object of 考えている. (I don't know if it is correct to say it's a *substitute* for を. 自分自身**をも** is possible too.)

The subject seems to be アイ, and the sentence describes how she thinks *of herself*. 他人事 literally means *someone else's matter*. The sentence basically says she are partially indifferent to herself (as well as other people, as implied by the も), which shouldn't be particularly contradictory, if not too normal (and that should be why it is mentioned).

Comment: Thanks. The reason I think this sentence is contradictory is because of ゲームのプレイヤーキャラ位に思っていて, which I understood as "think of herself as a main character."

Comment: @JohnDavies There's no word meaning *main*. It says *a game player (on the screen, say)*.  It says she has a kind of 3rd person perspective on herself.

Comment: @JohnDavies プレーヤーキャラ is certainly a main character *in a game*, but it's far less important than the player herself in the real world.